# Drab "delete comment" box style

Tags: feature-request, deleted-comments

Soo...when I go to delete a comment, I get a rather drab box popping up in the middle of my browser window like so:

[image: image of comment box]

Could we perhaps reformat the box so that it has this kind of style to it:

[image: image of right sidebar listing blog stuff]

Or, even better, make the box some sort of "callout" style thing that extends out of the delete button and shrinks away after you select an option? (lol I apologize for my lackluster art)

[image: image of comment pop up]

Fix: Under recommendation from Will's comment, I'm freehanding the box:

[image]

Comment: The box is just a JavaScript `confirm()` box, and the style of the box is dependent on your browser. It's guaranteed to work with every browser and fit with it's style choices with no developer effort.

Comment: the confirm box works. Let's put this way down on the list so other pressing matters can be taken on first.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the tip. Does that mean that it isn't modifiable at all since we run the risk of losing browser compatibility?

Comment: Why, what is wrong with the current  confirm box?

Comment: Nothing is fundamentally wrong with it, of course, it works as rene mentions. I was saying it could use some styling to match with the Stack Overflow color palette such as the light orange, but looks like people disagree (np with that either).

Comment: @takanuva15 Yep, don't get nervous if this post/suggestion gets downvoted, it's not personal (And doesn't affect your reputation) - It just show people agree/disagree with this suggestion

Comment: I'd argue that if they were to change it to match the style of the site, it should look like the dialog for flagging. The yellow background is for either quotations in posts or highlighting blog & meta articles. It doesn't really make sense for a confirm box. But ultimately I also don't think it's worth the effort to change it.

Comment: I think your question is getting downvotes because the design of the delete confirmation dialog is... somewhat ... Should I be diplomatic or truthful?  Okay, diplomatic... It looks like dog poop.  I suggest creating a new one made of freehand circles.  You'll get upvotes.  Trust me.

Comment: Lol will do, I'll get on it now

Comment: @Will does the new box work?

Comment: I didn't record the score before the change! Maybe? But nice try! YAS!

Comment: Minor: use  Yes/No or OK/Cancel.  Unless it's common you answer the question *Do you want coffee?* with *Cancel*. Might be Canadian, not sure.

Answer (score 5):

I feel that this is a terrible idea. One of the biggest problems with the usability of web applications is that they are forced to constantly re-invent the wheel when it comes to the user interface because there is very little in the way of [standards](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95602/why-do-dialogs-have-grey-backgrounds/95621#95621). On the other hand, desktop applications have been highly standardized in their UI for many years, and this has always been a massive boon to usability. (In recent years, unfortunately, desktop app designers have been taking a cue from their web-designer brethren and degrading the consistency and usability there, too.)

The current dialog box is generated by your browser using JavaScript and is guaranteed to match the theme of your system, which makes it instantly more familiar and usable. It's okay that dialog boxes are "drab". They aren't meant to be pretty, they're meant to be *functional*. There are all kinds of "little things" that designers get wrong when they reinvent the wheel that the OS-generated dialogs get right out of the box. One of the classic examples is keyboard shortcuts. I can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to interact with the dialog that is currently generated. I can alternatively press a letter key corresponding to the option of my choosing. Would your custom-designed dialog have that same behavior? Maybe, but most of the time I see these, they don't.

Why does a dialog box need to look like the Community Bulletin? That seems like a *disadvantage* to me—they are obviously quite different mechanisms.

The "callout" idea is interesting, but ultimately unnecessary, since this is a *modal* dialog. You know what invoked it, and you cannot possibly forget, since you cannot continue interacting with the site until you deal with the message box. If there is really a concern about confusion regarding which comment the prompt is referring to, then it could be addressed by reproducing a portion of the comment in the dialog box itself.

The only thing I do like over the original is your proposed wording.

> Are you sure you want to delete this comment?

is much more natural than

> Really delete this comment?

Comment: Wow, nice answer on that ux stackexchange post. Explains a lot about the default formatting of these dialogs.

Comment: I totally agree about changing the wording. When I saw that it made me think some developer was just trying to be funny. I actually found this post because I searched for "Really delete this comment" to see if there was discussion for why it _still_ hasn't been fixed.